Powershell Creating Button by Hastable with dynamic Variable
I'd like to create a couple of buttons by using a hashtable.
The problem is that the creating and access of dynamic Variables don't work.
Here is my script:
$ButtonList = @{
    'NumPad1' = "Enter"
    'NumPad2'  = "ESC"
}


function WriteButtonName ($sBName){
    Write-Host $sBName
    
}



$x_pos= 35

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
foreach($b in $ButtonList.GetEnumerator()){
$Name = $($b.Name) 
$Value = $($b.Value)


    New-Variable -Name $Name -Value New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    #$(get-variable -Name $Name) = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    (get-variable -Name $Name).Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($x_pos,35)
    (get-variable -Name $Name).Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
    (get-variable -Name $Name).Text = $Value
    (get-variable -Name $Name).Add_Click({WriteButtonName -sBName $Name })

$x_pos += 130

}

The Error is:

New-Variable - No position parameter was found that accepts the
System.Windows.Forms.Button argument.

Where are my mistakes? Thanks.

are you using powershell 2.0? Only tag it if the issue is only happening on that specific version. Note that ps2.0 is very old and included in Windows 7 which is no longer supported

What doesn’t work exactly? Do you get an error, or unexpected behaviour (and what I’m is the current & expected behaviour)? Note that you’re not adding your button to the form so they won’t appear on it, and your code might be simpler if you pack the buttons into a second hashtable rather than create dynamic variables…

and calling get-variable -Name $Name repeatedly is a waste of resource. Just store it in a variable

In that way it works:
foreach($b in $ButtonList.GetEnumerator()){
$Name = $($b.Name) 
$Value = $($b.Value)

    Remove-Variable -Name $Name
    New-Variable -Name $Name #-Value New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    (get-variable -Name $Name).Value = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    (get-variable -Name $Name).Value.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($x_pos,35)
    (get-variable -Name $Name).Value.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
    (get-variable -Name $Name).Value.Text = $Value
    (get-variable -Name $Name).Value.Add_Click({WriteButtonName -sBName $Name })

$x_pos += 130

}

Don't Know Why I always have to choose the ".value".
If I make '$Button = ... .Form.Button' , I can user '$Button.size ...' direkly. (?)

Because get-variable returns a System.Management.Automation.PSVariable object, which has properties like Name, Description and Value property - in your case the Value contains a reference to a System.Windows.Forms.Button. Compare that to $Button = ... .Form.Button - $Button is a reference to a System.Windows.Forms.Button.

Hi, Here are the last version:https://stackoverflow.com/a/78680013/21499900
